# Segmentation Fault - String Concatenation in C Error

Tags: c

I am fairly new to C programming and still trying to understand all the nooks and crannies of C.  I am writing a program to concatenate two strings.  But I am getting an error which I don't understand. Here is the output.

**Asfakul

The Length of the String name is 7

The Length of the String fullname is 7

L

Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int  main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  char *name="Asfakul";
  char *surname="Laskar";
  char *fullname;
  int i=0;
  //Allocate Memory of 100 char 
  fullname=(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
  fullname=name;
  while(*name !='\0')
  {
    i++;
    name++;
  }

  // Allocate Memory for FullName

  //fullname=(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
  //Coppied the spurce String
 // fullname=name; // Here this assignement will not work as Pointer name now point to NULL character of String Name.
  puts(fullname);
  printf("The Length of the String name is %d\n",i );
  printf("The Length of the String fullname is %d\n",strlen(fullname) );

  while(*surname !='\0')
  {
    printf("%c\n",*(fullname+i+1));
    *(fullname+i+2)=*(surname);
    printf("%c\n",*(surname));
    i++;
    surname++;

  }
  puts(fullname);



  return 0;
}
```

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you want to use `strcat`

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C.

Comment: @user2079303  I dont understand what you are saying , please explain.

Comment: @Ôrel   I want to write a concatenation program.  So cant use strcat

Comment: This is a call to `malloc` and you cast the result to `char*`: `(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));` Don't do that. Do this instead: `malloc(100*sizeof(char));` ...or `malloc(100)` because `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

Answer (score 6):

`fullname = name;` assigns the pointer `name` to `fullname`. You subsequently modify the data at `name`. That's not allowed since `name` points to a *read-only* string literal.

You're also discarding the `malloc` pointer, leaving you no way to `free` the allocated memory! This will not end well.

You should take a deep copy of `name` instead: consider using a `strncpy`.

If you were to use `const char*` for the string literals then compilation should fail, so protecting yourself from these kind of things.

Comment: @Batheseba   Could you please explain the sentence "You're also discarding the malloc pointer, leaving you no way to free the allocated memory! This will not end well."

Comment: You understand that `fullname=name;` is assigning the pointer to `fullname`. Therefore, how can you call `free` with the pointer that `malloc` returned back to you?

Comment: What happens when I assign a pointer to another pointer?  Does the starting address gets copied to the new pointer and new pointer now points to the old starting point now?

Answer (score 0):

```
*(fullname+i+2)=*(surname);
```

Here you are trying to cat the surname at the end of the name:

```
  char *name="Asfakul";
```

This is read-only space.

You should alloc enough space for both strings and copy them inside the allocated space.

Answer (score 0):

You can past char by char

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int  main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  char *name="Asfakul";
  char *surname="Laskar";
  char *fullname;
  int i=0;
  //Allocate Memory of 100 char 
  fullname=malloc(100*sizeof(char));
  while(*name !='\0')
  {
    fullname[i++] = *name++;
  }

  fullname[i] = '\0';

  puts(fullname);
  printf("The Length of the String name is %d\n",i );
  printf("The Length of the String fullname is %zd\n",strlen(fullname) );
  fullname[i++] = ' ';
  while(*surname !='\0')
  {
    fullname[i++]= *surname++;    
  }
  fullname[i] = '\0';

  puts(fullname);

  free(fullname);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should add a test on i to avoid overflow and free the memory at this end

Comment: **1)** `printf("The Length of the String fullname is %d\n",strlen(fullname) );` here you print `strlen` which is `size_t` using `%d`, should be `%zu`. **2)** Please `free` what you [`malloc`](http://ideone.com/zF2Cb9).